# read metadata of a Doctrine entity property

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, properties, metadata

I have to following entity :

```
/**
 * ProductService
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="sf_products_services")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\ProductServiceRepository")
 */
class ProductService
{
    [...]

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=150)
     */
    protected $name;

    [...]
```

How can I read the "length" value of the $name property ? I read I could use doctrine metadata, but I dont find anything about how to use it and how to read these data.

Comment: Hi @VaN if mine or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In accordion with the @wonde answer you can read the info you need thru the Doctrine metadata info as follow:

```
    $doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get("doctrine");
    $em = $doctrine->getManager();

    $className = "Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\ProductService";

    $metadata = $em->getClassMetadata($className);

    $nameMetadata = $metadata->fieldMappings['name'];

    echo $nameMetadata['type'];  //print "string"
    echo $nameMetadata['length']; // print "150"
```

Hope this help

Comment: Just quickly adding that getClassMetadata() returns a ClassMetadataInfo object, which has many useful methods: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/php-mapping.html#field-association-getters. You can use getFieldMapping('name'), check if a field is unique, if the PK is Uuid isIdentifierUuid(), the type of generator used for the id, and a whole lot more.

Answer (score 11):

getClassMetadata( mixed $className ) Returns the ORM metadata descriptor for a class

e.g

```
$metadata = $entityManager->getClassMetadata($className);
```

"The class name must be the fully-qualified class name without a leading backslash (as it is returned by get_class($obj)) or an aliased class name.
Examples: MyProject\Domain\User sales:PriceRequest"

Comment: use  $metadata->fieldMappings['name'] to get the properties